# Where can I find a metal circular trim?

Tags: wood, trim

I am cutting a large circular hole in some Ikea furniture and I need a metal trim to cover inside of the hole. I'm not sure what the right words are that would describe this part. Do you know where I might find something that can cover the inside of a circle cut out of wood?

What I'm looking for is something that looks like this and is roughly 10-15 cm in diameter, but in two pieces so each side is protected. I'm not sure what they are called though?

[image]

Comment: If you are just covering the inside, and not a border around the top, then you don't need a metal circle, you need a flexible metal strip to run along the inside of the circle, correct?

Comment: Hi, I need something that will cover the inside with a lip that overlaps the edges to protect the edges of the circle. I was imagining that there might be metal circles that could be bought is set diameters and possibly depths (or preferably adjustable depth). I have no idea what you might call it, coving maybe?

Comment: What is the intended purpose of the hole? Decoration, cables, hardware? That will affect the suggestion.

Comment: Hi, good question. It's for a home made rage cage. I need to create a hole between some wood in the middle of the furniture so the rats can get through. I need something to protect the edges of both sides of the circle/hole so the rats don't get caught on it or nibble, hence why some kind of metal would be ideal. Bit random I know. :)

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for a **desk grommet**?

[image]

I would recommend getting the trim piece prior to making the hole, as your size options will not be unlimited.

Comment: That's not a bad Idea. I might start searching for them and see what comes up.

Comment: You can use one on each side to protect both edges, if the wood is thick enough. You can get these in many sizes and finishes.